# Intent Attach Data to set wallpaper android Getting Error on some devices

Tags: java, android, android-intent

The same code works fine on some mobile phones but gives error on others

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.setData(photoURI);
    intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/*");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set as:"), 7575);
```

Comment: @Alo Rehman What error you are facing. Provide that error.

Comment: Can you specify in which android version and what error has been occured

Comment: It is comming in samsung j1 i cant set wallpaper through default wallpaper app but i can set through wallpaper app of google it showing toast wallpaper already deleted

Comment: And the path i am getting is like this    ` String path1=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ "/SomeFolder/"+Images_list.mThumbIds[Integer.parseInt(s)]+".jpg`